# Shaking CSS Zoom on Edge

Tags: html, css

I want to make an image slowly zoom in and out using css.
I'm using the following code:

```
.dv{
    background:url('http://placekitten.com/g/300/300');
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transition: transform linear 10s;
}
```

Here is a demo:

http://jsbin.com/duhugibifu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

On chrome and firefox it runs really smooth, but on Edge the image shakes.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: It doesn't shake on Edge for me unless I let it zoom all the way in/out before changing zoom direction. When it finishes zooming all the way, the image seems to shift slightly, which might be related to why it shakes. Bizarre.

Comment: This issue isn't just with Edge, IE does the same thing. I spent quite a while looking at how people are doing what you are trying to do, and they all have the same issue you do (whether they realize it or not). The issue is not the zooming, it is the repositioning, and that shaking will happen whether you zoom or not. 
https://jsfiddle.net/869131fd/18/
So in this case it is not the zoom, it is the centering of the background that causes the issue.

Comment: Your example does not shake here. Runs smoothly on edge.

Comment: Click "zoom", wait one second, then click "zoom" again before animation completes. This time wait for it to complete animation. Now click it one last time and the shaking can be seen.